# CoreData not saving - TableViewCell returning nill

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is my code:

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreData

    class ExerciseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            //sets stepper configs
            setsStepper.wraps = false
            setsStepper.autorepeat = true
            setsStepper.continuous = true
            setsStepper.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
            setsStepper.minimumValue = 0
            setsStepper.maximumValue = 500
            setsStepper.value = 0

            //reps stepper configs
            repsStepper.wraps = false
            repsStepper.autorepeat = true
            repsStepper.continuous = true
            repsStepper.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            repsStepper.minimumValue = 0
            repsStepper.maximumValue = 500
            repsStepper.value = 0

            exerciseTableView.reloadData()
        }

        var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?

        @IBOutlet var exerciseTableView: UITableView!

        @IBOutlet var dayName: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet var exerciseName: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet var setsStepper: UIStepper!
        @IBOutlet var repsStepper: UIStepper!

        @IBOutlet var setsNumber: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var repsNumber: UILabel!

        var daysArray = [String]()
        var namesArray = [String]()
        var setsArray = [Int]()
        var repsArray = [Int]()


        func appendDaysToArray() {
            let dayLabel = dayName.text
            daysArray.append(dayLabel)

            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDay", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
            let trainingday = TrainingDay(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
            trainingday.day = dayName.text

            var error: NSError?
            moc?.save(&error)

            if let err = error {
                var status = err.localizedFailureReason
                println("\(status)")
            } else {
                println("Day #\(dayName.text) saved successfully!")
            }
        }

        func appendNamesToArray () {
            let nameLabel = exerciseName.text
            namesArray.append(nameLabel)

            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDetails", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
            let trainingdetails = TrainingDetails(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
            trainingdetails.exerciseName = exerciseName.text

            var error: NSError?
            moc?.save(&error)

            if let err = error {
                var status = err.localizedFailureReason
                println("\(status)")
            } else {
                println("Exercise: #\(exerciseName.text) saved successfully!")
            }

        }

        func appendNumberToSets () {
            let numberOfSets = setsNumber.text?.toInt()
            setsArray.append(numberOfSets!)

            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDetails", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
            let trainingdetails = TrainingDetails(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
            trainingdetails.setsNumber = setsNumber.text!

            var error: NSError?
            moc?.save(&error)

            if let err = error {
                var status = err.localizedFailureReason
                println("\(status)")
            } else {
                println("Exercise: #\(setsNumber.text) saved successfully!")
            }

        }

        func appendNumberOfReps () {
            let numberOfReps = repsNumber.text?.toInt()
            repsArray.append(numberOfReps!)

            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDetails", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
            let trainingdetails = TrainingDetails(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
            trainingdetails.repsNumber = repsNumber.text!

            var error: NSError?
            moc?.save(&error)

            if let err = error {
                var status = err.localizedFailureReason
                println("\(status)")
            } else {
                println("Exercise: #\(repsNumber.text) saved successfully!")
            }

        }

        @IBAction func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {
            println("\(dayName.text)")
            appendDaysToArray()
            println("\(exerciseName.text)")
            appendNamesToArray()
            println("\(setsNumber.text)")
            appendNumberToSets()
            println("\(repsNumber.text)")
            appendNumberOfReps()
            exerciseTableView.reloadData()
        }

        @IBAction func setsStepperAction(sender: UIStepper) {
            println("\(Int(sender.value))")
            setsNumber.text = Int(sender.value).description
        }

        @IBAction func repsStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
            println("\(Int(sender.value))")
            repsNumber.text = Int(sender.value).description
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return namesArray.count
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cellIdentifier = "exerciseCell"
    var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
            if cell == nil {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            }
            let row = indexPath.row
                let name = namesArray[indexPath.row]
            let numberReps = repsArray[indexPath.row]
            let numberSets = setsArray[indexPath.row]
                cell!.textLabel!.text = name
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "Sets: #\(numberSets) Reps: #\(numberReps)"
            return cell!
        }
    }
```

and

```
class ViewExercisesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchTrainingDetails(), managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)
        self.viewExerciseTableView.reloadData()


        sundayButton.frame = CGRectMake(-30,150,125,125)
        sundayButton.addTarget(self, action: "sundayButtonTouch:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        sundayButton.setImage(imageSunday, forState: .Normal)
        sundayButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30,30,30,30)
        self.view.addSubview(sundayButton)

        mondayButton.frame = CGRectMake(120,150,125,125)
        mondayButton.addTarget(self, action: "mondayButtonTouch:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        mondayButton.setImage(imageMonday, forState: .Normal)
        mondayButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30,30,30,30)
        self.view.addSubview(mondayButton)

        tuesdayButton.frame = CGRectMake(270,150,125,125)
        tuesdayButton.addTarget(self, action: "tuesdayButtonTouch:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        tuesdayButton.setImage(imageTuesday, forState: .Normal)
        tuesdayButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30,30,30,30)
        self.view.addSubview(tuesdayButton)

        wednesdayButton.frame = CGRectMake(-30,250,125,125)
        wednesdayButton.addTarget(self, action: "wednesdayButtonTouch:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        wednesdayButton.setImage(imageWednesday, forState: .Normal)
        wednesdayButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30,30,30,30)
        self.view.addSubview(wednesdayButton)

        thursdayButton.frame = CGRectMake(70,250,125,125)
        thursdayButton.addTarget(self, action: "thursdayButtonTouch:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        thursdayButton.setImage(imageThursday, forState: .Normal)
        thursdayButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30,30,30,30)
        self.view.addSubview(thursdayButton)

        fridayButton.frame = CGRectMake(170,250,125,125)
        fridayButton.addTarget(self, action: "fridayButtonTouch:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        fridayButton.setImage(imageFriday, forState: .Normal)
        fridayButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30,30,30,30)
        self.view.addSubview(fridayButton)

        saturdayButton.frame = CGRectMake(270,250,125,125)
        saturdayButton.addTarget(self, action: "saturdayButtonTouch:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        saturdayButton.setImage(imageSaturday, forState: .Normal)
        saturdayButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30,30,30,30)
        self.view.addSubview(saturdayButton)


    }

    //VAR AND LET

    var sundayButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    var imageSunday = UIImage(named: "day.png")

    var mondayButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    var imageMonday = UIImage(named: "day.png")

    var tuesdayButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    var imageTuesday = UIImage(named: "day.png")

    var wednesdayButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    var imageWednesday = UIImage(named: "day.png")

    var thursdayButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    var imageThursday = UIImage(named: "day.png")

    var fridayButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    var imageFriday = UIImage(named: "day.png")

    var saturdayButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    var imageSaturday = UIImage(named: "day.png")

    @IBOutlet var viewExerciseTableView: UITableView!

    var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?

    // FUNCTIONS

    func sundayButtonTouch(sender: UIButton!) {
        println("future event will be added, button working fine - sunday")
    }

    func mondayButtonTouch(sender: UIButton!) {
        println("future event will be added, button working fine - monday")
    }

    func tuesdayButtonTouch(sender: UIButton!) {
        println("future event will be added, button working fine - tuesday")
    }

    func wednesdayButtonTouch(sender: UIButton!) {
        println("future event will be added, button working fine - wednesday")
    }

    func thursdayButtonTouch(sender: UIButton!) {
        println("future event will be added, button working fine - thursday")
    }

    func fridayButtonTouch(sender: UIButton!) {
        println("future event will be added, button working fine - friday")
    }

    func saturdayButtonTouch(sender: UIButton!) {
        println("future event will be added, button working fine - saturday")
    }

    // FETCH REQUEST METHODS
    func fetchTrainingDay() -> NSFetchRequest {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDay")
       // let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "day == %@")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "day", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.predicate = nil
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        return fetchRequest
    }

    func fetchTrainingDetails() -> NSFetchRequest {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDetails")
        fetchRequest.predicate = nil
        let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "exerciseName", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "repsNumber", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptor3 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "setsNumber", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, sortDescriptor3]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        return fetchRequest
    }



    //TABLE VIEW DELEGATE METHODS
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "exCell"
        var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell

        if let exCell = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? TrainingDetails {
            println("THE ERROR IS HERE #\(exCell.exerciseName) \(exCell.repsNumber) \(exCell.setsNumber)")
            cell!.textLabel?.text = exCell.exerciseName
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "Sets: #\(exCell.setsNumber) Reps: #\(exCell.repsNumber)"
        }
        return cell!
    }

    // MARK: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.viewExerciseTableView.beginUpdates()
    }
    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject,
        atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
        newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)
    {
        switch(type) {
        case .Insert:
            if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                viewExerciseTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath],
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        case .Delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                viewExerciseTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath],
                    withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        case .Update:
            break
        case .Move:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                    viewExerciseTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath],
                        withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
                    viewExerciseTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath],
                        withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo,
        atIndex sectionIndex: Int,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)
    {
        switch(type) {
        case .Insert:
            viewExerciseTableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex),
                withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        case .Delete:
            viewExerciseTableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex),
                withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        viewExerciseTableView.endUpdates()
    }





}
```

and

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class TrainingDetails: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var exerciseName: String
    @NSManaged var setsNumber: String
    @NSManaged var repsNumber: String
    @NSManaged var relationship2: NSManagedObject

}
```

The logic is this: In "ExerciseViewController", I put some stuff in CoreData, this view works fine. Now, in ViewExercisesViewController, I should retrieve the exerciseName and set it as the cell's textLabel, but it crashes right here:   `println("THE ERROR IS HERE #\(exCell.exerciseName) \(exCell.repsNumber) \(exCell.setsNumber)")`. It seems that I'm not retrieving it correctly, but I'm certain it is being saved in CoreData.

Anyone has any idea? I have an app that does something similar, but this one is not working.

Thanks for your help, I'm looking forward to figure out what's wrong here.

**EDIT** -> image with crush error:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Doing this:
[image]

leads to this:

[image]

**FINAL EDIT** -> **SOLUTION**

As Tom said, doing this:

```
func appendTrainingDetails () {
        let nameLabel = exerciseName.text
        namesArray.append(nameLabel)
        let numberOfSets = setsNumber.text?.toInt()
        setsArray.append(numberOfSets!)
        let numberOfReps = repsNumber.text?.toInt()
        repsArray.append(numberOfReps!)

        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDetails", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let trainingdetails = TrainingDetails(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        trainingdetails.exerciseName = exerciseName.text
        trainingdetails.setsNumber = setsNumber.text!
        trainingdetails.repsNumber = repsNumber.text!

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            var status = err.localizedFailureReason
            println("\(status)")
        } else {
            println("Exercise: #\(exerciseName.text) saved successfully!")
            println("Number of sets: #\(setsNumber.text) saved successfully!")
            println("Number of reps: #\(repsNumber.text) saved successfully!")
        }
    }
```

with the methods, led me to fix what I was doing wrong! Thank you very very much!!

Comment: What error message(s) get printed when the crash occurs?

Comment: I updated the question. Any idea?? @TomHarrington

Comment: @NicholasPiccoli can you NSPredicate with exerciseName != nil  in fetchTrainingDetails(), i know this is not soution but by doing this you can debug the exact issue .

Comment: @hardik.shah I updated the question!

Comment: @NicholasPiccoli oh man you are doing totally wrong here you are calling all append method each and every time for exercisename,setsNumber and repsNumber that means insted of one object it store 3 objects in every object will be fill with only single property and other two property will be set to nil .. because you are not updating your old object you are calling append method but creating new object everytime. this is wrong

Comment: @hardik.shah Got what you said. But how would I do it correctly?

Comment: @NicholasPiccoli check Tom Answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what it looks like is happening...

Your methods `appendNumberToSets()`, `appendNumberOfReps()`, and `appendNamesToArray()` all have this code:

```
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDetails", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
let trainingdetails = TrainingDetails(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
```

That means that **each one of these** is creating a new instance of `TrainingDetails`. However,

- `appendNumberToSets()` *only* sets a value for the `setsNumber` property
- `appendNamesToArray()` *only* sets a value for the `exerciseName` property
- `appendNumberOfReps()` *only* sets a value for the `repsNumber` property

In all three methods you're creating new `TrainingDetails` instances but leaving most of the properties with nil values. *That would be OK* except that later on you attempt to look up `exerciseName`, `setsNumber`, and `repsNumber` *on the same instance*. Since none of your instances have values for all three, your app crashes.

This is happening because Core Data has an idea of what an optional value is, and Swift also has an idea of what "optional" means, but **these are not the same thing**. Core Data doesn't care that you're leaving these properties with nil values, but Swift does. The conflict between these two ideas is leading to your problem.

What you should do:

- **If these values should be optional**, that is, they're allowed to be nil, you should change your `TrainingDetails` class to make them Swift optionals. It looks like you're using code that Xcode generated, but **that code is wrong** and it's completely OK to fix it. The compiler will then force you to check whether the attributes have values, and you won't crash.
- **If these values should not be optional**, that is, any `TrainingDetails` must have values for every one of these attributes, you should do two things. First, edit your Core Data model. For each of these attributes, un-check the "Optional" box in the model editor. That way Core Data will know that nil isn't allowed and it will prevent you from saving changes if you have unexpected nils. Second, you need to change the three methods mentioned above to either (a) always assign values to all of the attributes, or (b) re-use the same `TrainingDetails` instance instead of creating a new one in each method (the choice depends on your requirements, so it's up to you to decide which is correct).

Comment: Thank you very very much! Really, I have never had an answer like yours here. You explained everything in some easy way that anyone can understand what happened and the solution. I updated the question with the answer.

Comment: I have one last question, if you don't mind. Since I'm still learning core data, could you explain to me how do I fetch the TrainingDetails for that specific TrainingDay? I can make a new question for this, if you think it's better. I really need to learn this!

Comment: You would use an `NSFetchRequest` with a `predicate` configured to match the attribute values for the `TrainingDay` you want to fetch. You only need to do that if you don't already have a reference to it, though-- you could add a property to your class to store the one you create in your code, so that you don't need to fetch it again.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `appendNumberOfReps()`, it seems that you are using dot syntax to add it to the `TrainingDay` object (not sure where you defined it, though I assume it is an NSManagedObject?). In your Core Data entity `TrainingDay`, create an attribute named `repsNumber` and I assume we can set it as a `String` and try this:

```
// Save To Core Data
let entityDescription =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDay", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
let trainingday = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

var error: NSError?
moc?.save(&error)

    trainingday.setValue(repsNumber.text!, forKey: "repsNumber")

    if !moc.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error)")
    } else {
        println("Exercise: #\(repsNumber.text) saved successfully!")
    }
```

Then in order for your tables to be set correctly, it would be easiest for them to set by reading the count and data off of an array. So maybe you can call Core Data to return the data and then append them to an array named `var repsArray: String = []`:

```
// Fetch From Core Data
let trainingFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"TrainingDay")
let fetchedResults = moc.executeFetchRequest(trainingFetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

    if let results = fetchedResults {

        if results.count > 0 {
            for index in 0...results.count-1 {

                let match = results[index] as NSManagedObject

                repsArray.append(match.valueForKey("repsNumber") as! String)
            }
        }

    }
```

Then it might be easier to count how many rows there should be in the table by using the `repsArray` (just for example) to return a row count:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return repsArray.count
}
```

And then as long as you have the right table cell class (for example, `CustomCell` below) and label names created in Interface Builder (for example, `repNumberLabel` below) and then attached to `CustomCell`, you can just use the indexPath.Row to work off of the arrays you built:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? CustomCell

    if !(cell != nil) {
        cell = CustomCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell?.repNumberLabel.text = self.repsArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

Hope this helps and wasn't redundant to what you already tried! This is what has worked for me when trying to save to Core Data and then retrieve to data for use in a table cell.

Comment: repsNumber is not set in TrainingDay core data model, it is set in TrainingDetails model. TrainingDay has a relationship to-many TrainingDetails, while TrainingDetails has a relationship to-one TrainingDay. Any idea how to fix it?